# can't load ubuntu after installing it

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader

Guys i was unable to find or understand what and how to do it, so i will ask.
I know there are more questions like mine, but i didn't understand, so sorry.

I have windows 7 installed on my laptop and i decided to install ubuntu 12.04.
The installation process was successful, but i can't start ubuntu.When i start my laptop
windows 7 start automatically.I tried with live usb stick checked in  ubuntu's /etc/default/ oppened grub file and wrote GRUB_DEFAULT = 2 , but nothing happend...

What i have to do to be able to choose which OS to boot?
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) --> Recommended Repair 
   [image]
2. Write  on a paper the URL (http://paste.xxxxxx) that will appear
3. Reboot the pc. If still any problem, indicate the URL.